# Can a submodule belong to multiple modules in YANG?

Tags: ietf-netmod-yang

I have a submodule which I would like to be used in two modules. Is it possible to use the one submodule in multiple modules and how to do that?

Comment: This question is perfectly clear and should not be closed.

Answer (score 0):

No. A submodule may only belong to one module and may be included only by its main module or a submodule that belongs to the same main module.

> Submodules are partial modules that contribute definitions to a
> module.  A module may include any number of submodules, but each
> submodule may belong to only one module.

> [RFC7950, Section 5.1, Modules and submodules](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7950#section-5.1)

> A submodule MUST only be included by either the module to which it
> belongs or another submodule that belongs to that module.

> [RFC7950, Section 7.2.2, The "belongs-to" statement](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7950#section-7.2.2)